# Как получить данные из поля формы?

Tags: javascript, html, form

Например, есть элементы:

```
<form id='forma'>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Имя">
    <button>Хочу познакомиться</button>

<script>var x;</script>
```

Нужно взять значение из `input#name`. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Взять значение после загрузки страницы? Или при клике на `button`?

Answer (score 3):

Можно забрать данные с помощью jQuery:

```
$('#name').val()
```

Или "простым" JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('name').value
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.forms[id]` - выбор формы

`.elements[id]` - выбор элемента в этой форме

`.value` - значение элемента

```
<form id='forma'>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Имя"/>
    <button onclick='alert(document.forms["forma"].elements["name"].value); return false'>Хочу познакомитЬся</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fd2Lfrka/

P.S. Больше информации на http://tsya.ru/

Comment: `onclick` - грустная затея, скажем прямо. Не говоря уж о том, что автор так и не ответил до сих пор когда ему нужно получать это значение.

Comment: онклик - это такая вариация псевдокода. В "настоящем сайте", разумеется, должен быть какой-нибудь там jquery с, допустим, .on('click') или там .on('submit'), и все такое, да и alert, наверное, не нужен, а нужно что-то сделать с полученным значением, но для иллюстрации принципа, не множа сущности, самое то, как мне кажется.

Comment: Нет, иллюстрация использования `onclick` приводит к тому, что его (и только его) потом активно используют. А потом без слёз не взглянешь на то, что наделают. И повторюсь: мы по-прежнему не знаем при каких условиях автору нужно значение. Я поэтому код вообще размещать не стал - посижу, подожду. Сейчас - это чистой воды гадание.

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {
    name: $('#name').val()
}
```

Comment: @ViVi, постарайтесь, пожалуйста, давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.